# Display other value than Id in dataTable asp .net core

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-ajax

I have 2 tables (customers and appointments) with a foreign key of customerId in appointments. I want to display the customerFirstName and customerLastName of the customer, but I can only pass customerId as data in my loadDataTable ajax function. I cannot do this because customerId is the only foreign key entity in my Appointment model. What can I do to be able to pass the customerFirstName and customerLastName data in my ajax function? [My appointment table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXsu8.png)

```
var dataTable;

$(document).ready(function () {
    loadDataTable();
});
function loadDataTable() {
    dataTable = $('#DT_load').DataTable({
"ajax": {
        "url": "/Appointment/getall/",
        "type": "GET",
        "datatype": "json"
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "customerId", "width": "auto" },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo:

Appointment table:

[image]

Appointment data:

[image]

Customer Table:

[image]

Customer data:

[image]

Appointment.cs:

```
public class Appointment
    {
        public int AppointmentId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
```

Customer.cs:

```
public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerFirstName { get; set; }
        public string CustomerLastName { get; set; }

    }
```

Action(GetAll):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllAsync()
        {
            List<Appointment> l=await _context.Appointment.Include(a => a.Customer).ToListAsync();
            return Json(l);
        }
```

View:

```
<table id="DT_load">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>AppointmentId</td>
            <td>CustomerFirstName</td>
            <td>CustomerLastName</td>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>

</table>
@section scripts{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script>
    var dataTable;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        loadDataTable();
    });
    function loadDataTable() {
        dataTable = $('#DT_load').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Appointment/getall",
                "dataSrc": ""
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "appointmentId" },
                { "data": "customer.customerFirstName" },
                { "data": "customer.customerLastName"},
            ]
        });
    }
</script>
}
```

result:
[image]

Comment: I modified some of your code and now it works! Huge thanks :)